# Display the discount percentage on the sale badge in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, percentage, badge

This works for simple products but gives me two errors for variable products. In the sale flash on the archive I get NAN% with error "A non-numeric value encountered".

My code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'add_percentage_to_sale_bubble' );
function add_percentage_to_sale_bubble( $html ) {
    global $product;
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    $output ='<span class="onsale">SALE<br>-'.$percentage.'%</span>';
    return $output;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**2020 Update** - *Revisited the code and handling grouped products.*

The code you are using is outdated since Woocommerce 3. Try the following instead, that handle variable products too *(and grouped products)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'add_percentage_to_sale_badge', 20, 3 );
function add_percentage_to_sale_badge( $html, $post, $product ) {

  if( $product->is_type('variable')){
      $percentages = array();

      // Get all variation prices
      $prices = $product->get_variation_prices();

      // Loop through variation prices
      foreach( $prices['price'] as $key => $price ){
          // Only on sale variations
          if( $prices['regular_price'][$key] !== $price ){
              // Calculate and set in the array the percentage for each variation on sale
              $percentages[] = round( 100 - ( floatval($prices['sale_price'][$key]) / floatval($prices['regular_price'][$key]) * 100 ) );
          }
      }
      // We keep the highest value
      $percentage = max($percentages) . '%';

  } elseif( $product->is_type('grouped') ){
      $percentages = array();

      // Get all variation prices
      $children_ids = $product->get_children();

      // Loop through variation prices
      foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ){
          $child_product = wc_get_product($child_id);

          $regular_price = (float) $child_product->get_regular_price();
          $sale_price    = (float) $child_product->get_sale_price();

          if ( $sale_price != 0 || ! empty($sale_price) ) {
              // Calculate and set in the array the percentage for each child on sale
              $percentages[] = round(100 - ($sale_price / $regular_price * 100));
          }
      }
      // We keep the highest value
      $percentage = max($percentages) . '%';

  } else {
      $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
      $sale_price    = (float) $product->get_sale_price();

      if ( $sale_price != 0 || ! empty($sale_price) ) {
          $percentage    = round(100 - ($sale_price / $regular_price * 100)) . '%';
      } else {
          return $html;
      }
  }
  return '<span class="onsale">' . esc_html__( 'SALE', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . $percentage . '</span>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: There is one issue in calculating percentages for variable products and the below code will fix it  `$percentages[] = ( floatval( $prices['regular_price'][ $key ] ) - floatval( $price ) ) / floatval( $prices['regular_price'][ $key ] ) * 100;` Because WooCommerce appends '.00' to sale prices and it causes issue.

Comment: this worked for me on wordpress 5.4.4 and woocommerce version 3.9.2