# Display the discount percentage after sale ribbon but keeping css styles in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to show the percentage after the word Sale!
so it would show sale XX% Off.
like this: [image: To look like this]

I found [Display the discount percentage on the sale badge in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558950/display-the-discount-percentage-on-the-sale-badge-in-woocommerce-3/52559420#52559420)

My code in theme's functions.php file is like:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'mc_sale_flash' ) ) {
    function mc_sale_flash() {
        $sale_flash = '<div class="ribbon red"><span class="onsale">' . __( 'Sale!', 'mediacenter' ) . '</span></div>';
        return $sale_flash;
    }
}
```

How can I get it to look just like the one currently showing like on [sale page](https://www.thevapour-hut.com/product-category/e-liquids/bargains/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using links to reference "how it is currently showing on ***" is going to make this question completely unusable in the future (for others with similar questions). This is one of the (rare) occasions where an image of your desired result would greatly improve your question.Consider taking a screenshot (or using a snipping tool) and adding this as an image to your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, the css which needed to be added to make it look like this
[image]

is:

```
span.onsale {
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

span.onsale:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border-top-width: 25px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    min-width: 78px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-top-color: #f8484a;
}
```

After adding the code from the above link.