# Change Woocommerce Sale Text for specific category only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Is there a hook to change the default Woocommerce "Sale!" text to custom text, for a specific product category only, or for specific products only?

Comment: Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the discount percentage on the sale badge in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558950/display-the-discount-percentage-on-the-sale-badge-in-woocommerce-3)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom PHP function with hooks

> ```
> function new_sale_badge() {
>       if( has_term( 'category_name', 'product_cat' ) ){
>       return 'New_sale_text';
>       }
>     }
>     
>     add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'new_sale_badge');
> ```

Code goes in the functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).